# How to Enable UTF-8 in PHP while displaying browser

Tags: php, utf-8

I've enabled UT8 in the MySQL config, PHP config and Apache config.

I can view the UT8 characters correctly in phpMyAdmin. The data is stored correctly in the MySQL db.

However, when I call the data on a PHP page, PHP displays a? instead of the characters from the db.

I've enabled UTf8 in the php.ini 
default_charset = "utf-8"

I've also called the header in the PHP page with the UTF8: 
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');

Is there something that I've missed? What do I need to do to get my PHP pages to display the character set correctly?

Note: phpMyAdmin displays UTF8 correctly from the db.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy to "forget" another option, though forget is probably the wrong word. You should tell your connection object to deliver UTF-8, doing so will make you independend of the actual settings of the database.

```
// tells the pdo connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
```

This is an example for PDO connections, examples for mysql and mysqli connections you can find [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Answer (score 0):

I think you got most of them.

Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to your HTML document.

Sending just the header is not enough.

Comment: here is the link you can see how it is displaying..
http://www.igoogleportal.com/portal/gadget.php?gadgetid=10360&curtabid=56&page=1&dirid=5002&query=Bhaskar&srhflg=1